# How to use v.net.connect & v.net.distance in QGIS graphical modeler?

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-modeler

I have been attempting to run the v.net.distance GRASS algorithm on vector layers in QGIS (2.18.12, on Windows) unsuccessfully. I assume that to prior to using this algorithm, you must connect each input to a network (e.g. road) layer (using v.net.connect), and take these inputs for the v.net.distance algorithm. For instance, using similar inputs mentioned in [this](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.net.distance.html) tutorial, the workflow using my data should be:

[image: V.net.distance workflow in modeler]

In line with the tutorial example, the 'Electric Cable' serves as the 'streets', the 'Generator' as the 'hospitals' and the 'Poles' as the schools. The algorithm currently returns no output, and no error report is being generated under processing > history, which makes it impossible to debug. The error currently is that v.net.connect returns no output, which as I understand it is a must input for v.net.distance. I read [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238563/how-to-use-v-net-distance-grass-in-qgis) post, but I don't think in my case the advanced parameters are required and/or are the issue here.

My goal is to get a line layer that has the minimum paths from the 'Generator' (one feature point layer) to each pole (multiple feature point layer), via the Electric Cable network (line layer). I already achieved this through plugins (e.g. Road Graph plugin) easily, but I'd like to run in the modeler.

UPDATE* I have been able to complete this workflow in GRASS, but not in QGIS.

Here is an illustration of what the Road Graph plugin does that I'd like to get recursively done with the modeler.
Green points - Poles
Blue Line - Electric Cable
Red Star - Generator
Red Line - Shortest path
[image]

Comment: If anyone has been able to use v.net.distance in QGIS and can share his experience please comment!

Comment: Have you solved this problem?. I am facing the similar problem